# Storing other user data on my users data

Tags: javascript, meteor, nosql

I am just curious if this is bad practice. On my user object, under the profile attribute I am planning on storing the users likes. For instance the object would be like this:

```
user = {
  ...
  profile: {
    likes: [
      {
        user: {
          _id: USER_ID,
          avatar: USER_AVATAR,
          username: USER_USERNAME
        }
        otherData: true
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

What concerns me about doing it this way is that if the user associated changes their avatar, it wouldn't be the same as the avatar associated to this user. Also likes could have an infinite amount so I am afraid that could get really hit my performance as the array grows.

Is there a better way to approach this? I know in a traditional database, i would have a separate table for this and use a join to pull the users likes.

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you add `idUser, avatar, username` before `profile`? Then, just link the `likes` with the previous `idUser`

Comment: i guess you answered your question by yourself. either you'll have static object & performance issue otherwise you need to make join query.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed aren't joins in NOSQL even worse on performance than my approach?

Comment: not join actually, what you need to store in the Like Collection is the profile object who likes and the id whose profile has been liked.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed If I go with that approach is there a way to add some type of scheduler to update the user avatar if the associated user changed their avatar. I am not that experienced with Meteor. I know this can be done via rails/laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concerns are valid. NOSQL databases can have data consistency issues that arise because data is not properly normalized and is stored in multiple places.

You can avoid these data consistency issues by storing *just* the userIDs in the likes array and then doing an application-level join to join the profile likes to the user data like follows:

```
likes: [
{_id: USER_ID1},
{_id: USER_ID2}
]
```

However, when you do this you are essentially going back to a relational model (but without all the benefits of SQL).

The "correct" solution will depend on your application and whether you care about the performance hit incurred by doing the join or whether you care about the possiblity of getting stale data.

Comment: Are application level joins really bad on performance? This all feels so dirty. I don't know people build complex apps without some type of relational data. Do they just not care about data inconsistencies?

Comment: If you are using a NOSQL database you probably are doing it for performance reasons. IE) Your data is huge and having one single relational database box is not going to cut it. In that case, I would suggest *not* doing the application-level join and instead duplicate the data. In the background, you should have a process that runs that will make your data *eventually consistent*. Again, this is much more complicated than using a simple relational database so if your data is tiny I'd suggest not reaching for a NOSQL database.

Comment: The reason I am using NOSQL is due to its the default by Meteor. I would love to use a relational database as I have the most experience with them and I think in a relational way (from years with MYSQL/POSTGRES). I can't wait for Meteor's apollo so I can finally use SQL. Do you know of any meteor schedulers I can use to make my data consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not do that. If you store likes on the user collection then your user doc will keep increasing.

You can create a new collection named likes or whatever you like. Then store a single doc for like in the newly created collection.